# SQLite: Not using PRIMARY KEY column in an index

Tags: sqlite

I have the following tables in a test SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (ord INTEGER, room TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX test_room_idx on test(room, ord);

CREATE TABLE "test2" (ord INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, room TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX test2_room_idx on test2(room, ord);
```

The data in both tables is identical: about 180000 rows, of which 150000 have `room='zO'`.

The problem is that a query on `test2` for a given `room` and a small range of `ord`s will not use the `ord` column of `test2_room_idx`:

```
sqlite> explain query plan SELECT * FROM test WHERE room = 'zO' AND ord between 500000 and 501000;
selectid    order       from        detail                                                                           
----------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0           0           0           SEARCH TABLE test USING COVERING INDEX test_room_idx (room=? AND ord>? AND ord<?)
sqlite> explain query plan SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE room = 'zO' AND ord between 500000 and 501000;
selectid    order       from        detail                                                         
----------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------------------------------------------------
0           0           0           SEARCH TABLE test2 USING COVERING INDEX test2_room_idx (room=?)
```

For 150000 rows, this isn't too bad, but my production data has millions of rows, and the query ends up taking seconds.

I have `ANALYZE`d both tables. The problem appears to be specific to columns which match the [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) requirements for `rowid`.

My questions are:

- Why is the `ord` column of `test2_room_idx` not being used for this query?
- Short of redefining my production table not to have `ord` as a `PRIMARY KEY`, any suggestions what I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries are optimized correctly in recent SQLite versions, so apparently this was a (now-fixed) bug.

Just update your SQLite.

Comment: I should have thought to check that. Indeed, it seems to have been fixed between 3.11.1 and 3.12.0.